# Merging tables in memory - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am calling API endpoints to retrieve data. How can I merge `df_jobs` and `df_stages` before I save it on a local machine? In normal circumstances, it would be

```py
inter = pd.merge(df_stages, df_jobs, how='left', left_on='jobs_id', right_on='id')
```

But if I do it, It throws the var assignment error.

```py
def data_extraction(endpoint, url):
    """The function calls an API depending on the endpoint, saves the outcome which later is merged with the relevant tables"""
    i = 1
    page_num = 300
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    while i <= page_num:
        param = { 'page': i, 'per_page': 100}
        formatted_url = furl(url).add(param).url
        r = requests.get(formatted_url, auth = (api_key, password))
        if r.status_code == 200:
            response = r.json()
            objects = json_normalize(response)
            df = df.append(objects, ignore_index=True)      
            df.columns
            for c in df.columns:
                df[c] = df[c].astype(str).str.strip('[')
                df[c] = df[c].astype(str).str.strip(']')              
            i += 1
            time.sleep(2)  
        else:
          print("Failed to read tickets, errors are displayed below,")
          response = json.loads(r.content)
          print(response["errors"])       
    if endpoint == 'stages':      
        df_stages = df        
    elif endpoint == 'jobs':    
        df_jobs = df          

jobs = data_extraction('jobs', 'https://')
stages = data_extraction('stages', 'https://')
```

Comment: where you trying to merge `df_stages, df_jobs` is it inside the function?

Comment: I tried to add it after while and after the last if and the result was the same - the assignment error.

Comment: post the error you getting while merging the dataframes

Comment: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'df_jobs' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```py
def data_extraction(endpoint, url):
    """The function calls an API depending on the endpoint, saves the outcome which later is merged with the relevant tables"""
    i = 1
    page_num = 300
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    while i <= page_num:
        param = { 'page': i, 'per_page': 100}
        formatted_url = furl(url).add(param).url
        r = requests.get(formatted_url, auth = (api_key, password))
        if r.status_code == 200:
            response = r.json()
            objects = json_normalize(response)
            df = df.append(objects, ignore_index = True)      
            df.columns
            for c in df.columns:
                df[c] = df[c].astype(str).str.strip('[')
                df[c] = df[c].astype(str).str.strip(']')              
            i += 1
            time.sleep(2)  
        else:
          print("Failed to read tickets, errors are displayed below,")
          response = json.loads(r.content)
          print(response["errors"])       
    return df     

df_jobs = data_extraction('jobs','https://')
df_stages = data_extraction('stages','https://')

inter = pd.merge(df_stages, df_jobs, how = 'left', left_on = 'jobs_id', right_on = 'id')
```

Comment: @eponkratova try printing the `df` inside the `data_extraction` function and see it printing the datframe or not

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any need of below piece of code in `data_extraction()` method

```
if endpoint == 'stages':      
        df_stages = df        
    elif endpoint == 'jobs':    
        df_jobs = df
```

Instead, return `df` from your **data_extraction()** and then merge dataframes after calling the function with endpoint 'stages' and 'jobs'

Also, you can add `df.empty` check to avoid joining empty df.

Eg:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2], 'name': ['Sam','Joe'], 'age': [12,19]})
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [2,3], 'name': ['Rachel','Hank'], 'age': [50,90]})

merged = pd.merge(left=df1, right=df, how='left', left_on='id', right_on='id')
```

Comment: Yes, agree, just wanted to do some manipulation for a particular endpoint but for now, take it out. Thank you, again

Comment: @eponkratova: Ok. Just few points to add. 
1) keep a try/catch block in your code. Helps in error handling
2) always have a df none/ df empty check
3) return and identifier from your method to identify that the data processing was successful or not